# Blazor WASM - Make only the selected row editable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to iterate through some Data in a Dictionary and showing them in a table in Blazor WASM. I put an Edit button on each datarow to make the selected row editable if I will, but when I click the button, it makes every row editable in the whole table, because of the loop.
What should I change in my code, to make only the selected row editable? Thank's for the possible answers ;)

```
@if (Metadata != null)
{
   @foreach (var c in Metadata)
   {
       <tr>
           <td><button type="submit" @onclick="toggleEdit">Edit</button></td>
           @if (IsEditable)
           {
               <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Key"></td>
               <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Value"></td>
           }
           else
           {
               <td>@c.Key</td>
               <td>@c.Value</td>
           }                                            
      </tr>
    }
}

@code
{
   public Dictionary<string, string> Metadata { get; set; }
   public bool IsEditable = false;

   private void toggleEdit()
   {
       IsEditable = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of the dictionary?

Comment: Sry I added it to the code! public Dictionary<string, string> Metadata { get; set; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, any button will apply on all rows, You need to make project know which row you wanna change.

Please follow this demo:

```
@{ 
    int i = 0;
}


@if (MyProperty != null)
{
    @foreach (var c in MyProperty)
    {
        var index = i;
        <tr id="@i">
            <td id="@i"><button type="submit"  @onclick="()=>toggleEdit(index)">Edit</button></td>
            @if (IsEditable[i])
            {
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Key"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Value"></td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td>@c.Key</td>
                <td>@c.Value</td>
            }
        </tr>
        i++;
    }

    
}



@code{

//For testing, I just hard code here

    Dictionary<string, string> MyProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
         {"A","AAAAA" },
         {"B","BBBBB" },
         {"C","CCCCC" },
         {"D","DDDDD" },

     };

    public bool[] IsEditable;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var count = MyProperty.Keys.Count;

        IsEditable = new bool[count];
    }


    private void toggleEdit (int index)
    {
        IsEditable[index] = true;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for your answer! I tried it but get an error in the line @if(IsEditable[i])... "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: I have provided all the code in my answer, You can check if there is something different in your project.

Comment: Hi,@meszyyy, According to the  error message, I speculate that your `IsEditable` was not successfully initialized in the `OnInitializedAsync` method, and you can find out what is different with the answer I provided or provide your code that I can help you check

Comment: Thx for the idea @Xinran Shen ! I will take a look at it today :)

Comment: OK, waiting for your response.

Comment: In the child component got the error, but implemented in the parent, your solution worked well. Thank you :) I'm not a Blazor expert, but I'm gonna try to find the problem with the child component.

Answer (score 2):

Make toggleEdit method accept a parameter:

```
<td><button type="submit" @onclick="@(()=> toggleEdit(c))">Edit</button></td>
```

And your method (we don't know what c is from your question):

```
private void toggleEdit(YourType c)
{
   c.IsEditable = true;
}
```

You need the boolean to be tied to your object, otherwise there is no way the code knows which row is suppose to be editable. I.e. your:

```
public bool IsEditable = false;
```

must be your object's property.

Another approach would be to directly access the object's property:

```
<td><button type="submit" @onclick="@(c.IsEditable = !c.IsEditable)">Edit</button></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can allow editing of each row individually by using a `boolean` `array` with the same length as the `Metadata` `dictionary`. This array will track the edit status of each dictionary value, allowing you to toggle between editable and non-editable status for each row.

It's important to note that with a dictionary, you can only change the values, not the keys. `Keys` do not have `setters`, so you can either remove a key or add a new one.

Demo: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/wys4fe48

Implementation:

```
@page "/"
<style>
    th, td {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>
<h3>@metadatas["Title"]</h3>
<br/>

@if (metadatas != null)
{
    <table class="table table-bordered" style="background-color: @metadatas["Background-color"];">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 150px;">Action</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 150px;">Key</th>
            <th scope="col">Value</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var metadata in metadatas)
        {
            var keys = metadatas.Keys.ToList();
            var index = keys.IndexOf(metadata.Key);
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">@(index + 1)</th>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <button type="button" 
                            class="btn @(Edits[index] ? "btn-secondary" : "btn-primary")"
                            @onclick="@(() => { Edits[index] = !Edits[index]; })">
                        @(Edits[index] ? "Disable Edit" : "Enable Value")
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td>@metadata.Key</td>
                @if (Edits[index])
                {
                    <td><input @bind-value="metadatas[metadata.Key]" 
                               type="text" 
                               class="form-control" 
                               style="background-color: antiquewhite;"/></td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td>@metadata.Value</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> metadatas { get; set; }
    private bool[] Edits;
    
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        metadatas = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        metadatas.Add("Title", "Make only the selected row editable");
        metadatas.Add("Background-color", "white");
        
        // for storing edit status of each dictionary value
        // this array has to be same length as the dictionary
        Edits = new bool[metadatas.Count()];
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

Output:
[image: Output]